Cannot get cors to work for the life of me
This is my first time using cors and node.js, I am trying to call a Web API hosted on one URL from another URL.
I cannot even get cors to work simple app.use(cors());
I tried more complex configurations with origins and whatnot, still no luck.
The api lives on https://api.example.app and is being called from https://myapp.example.app
I am getting all kinds of cors errors.
Note, I am also using CloudFlare and Nginx Proxy Manager
Also, I CAN go to the https://api.example.app/select and get back my data that way without issue. But thats the only scenario working.
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var port = 3333;

app.use(express.text());

app.use(cors());

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: '192.168.1.200',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb'
});

app.get('/select', (req, res) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM mytable', (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
            return res.status(500).send('Failed to retrieve data from database');
        }
        console.log('Data retrieved successfully:', results);
        res.status(200).json(results);
    });
});

app.post('/insert', (req, res) => {
    var string = req.body;

    console.log(req.body);

    if (!string) {
        return res.status(400).send('String is required');
    }

    pool.query('INSERT INTO mytable(user) VALUES (?)', string, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error inserting string into database:', err);
            return res.status(500).send('Failed to insert string into database');
        }

        console.log('String inserted successfully');
        return res.status(200).send('String inserted successfully');
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://192.168.1.200:${port}`);
});

Errors with the current config above.

"I am getting all kinds of cors errors." please post the exact error messages from the browser console ... Because the backend code you are showing is fine

Added within link under code. @derpirscher

What’s your CORs config look like? Are you permitting all cross-site requests? Have you permitted your front-end’s origin?

@DanAshley - no point to specify origin as a header on the FE, you can't control that, it's passed by the browser and can't be overridden.

@RyanPierceWilliams correct me if I am wrong, but isnt my CORs config just the 'app.use(cors());' which from what I know, just allows any cross site action to happen?

This seems like a cloudflare/nginx issue. It doesn't look like the request is getting to your app - app.use(cors()) - enables CORS for all.

@AdamJenkins I removed that now, same erorrs. It was part of my troubleshooting.

@DanAshley - removing it wasn't going to fix anything, I was just pointing out it was superfluous (or rather unnecessary). Start investigating your nginx proxy configuration (I'm not sure what you mean by that) but it doesn't appear like the issue lies within your express application.

@AdamJenkins any settings in either CF or Nginx I should try?? Happy to jump on a discord or something too for quicker troubleshooting.

@DanAshley I'm not familiar with configuring CORS rules in CF, all I know is that your issue isn't in the code above. Maybe just start with the docs?

@AdamJenkins I did install an extension to bypass the cors, now I just
'POST https://api.exmaple.app/insert 403 (Forbidden)'

@DanAshley - wonderful! Something else is giving your a 403, likely in cloudflare. It's very common to see these CORS errors in the console that aren't actually CORS errors, which is what you have here. This isn't a CORS problem, it's (likely) a cloudflare configuration problem.

@DanAshley - what product are you using? A CF worker? Does this help?

I am just using a CF domain name for DNS. Not sure what a worker is.

@AdamJenkins I am checking some steps from ChatGPT for CF and cors now.

@DanAshley - it's not a CORS error - it's a red herring. Where is your actual running code hosted if you're just using CF for DNS?

@DanAshley - I can prove it to you. If you add a log at the top of your insert route, and you POST with your CORS extension enabled (so you won't get a CORS error) - you will see that the log never gets executed. That's because the route never gets hit, because something else is blocking it. Do you have any other middleware in your app that you aren't showing?

I think I have it back to working with a combination of Cloudflare configs, but unfortunately, I am not confident in which settings are helping or not helping. All I know is that it works. So I don't really want to post an answer unless I can just say this, but I do want to close the issue...
Cloudflare settings seem to take a little while to not be in affect from my testing where it would work one day after changing a setting but not the next. Maybe a caching thing.
If someone wants to look at my CF config on a discord screenshare to help determine what should be setup or not. I would still be open to that to help come to a clear conclusion. Otherwise, its dust in the wind.
Thanks everyone.

the 403 forbidden issue i solved by adding a Cloudflare page rule to
https://myapp.exmaple.app/*   Always Use HTTPS.
I was able to insert into the DB from my webpage ONLY now with using "Allow CORS" google chrome extension.
Update. I THINK i got it working with a combo of above AND turning off my WAF rule for only USA challenges.

@AdamJenkins now just for the CORS issue.

I'm very confused, you can't use cloudflare pages for an express server. You mentioned above you're using CF just for DNS - how does a cloudflare page rule affect CF DNS? Where is your express server hosted? Is the server code you posted a 100% accurate representation of your real deployed code (i.e. do you have any other middleware)?

Is this relevant at all?

I am not a network wiz, obviously. so maybe ai got some lingo wrong. I have a webpage hosted on my unraid server using nginx, then i have the domain name from CF, which I proxy with nginx proxy manager? lol

@AdamJenkins I tried that. I have been getting this today. Access to fetch at 'https://api.lucidnet.app/insert' from origin 'https://multistreamer.lucidnet.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

@AdamJenkins it was working for a full day or two but not anymore.

Right now that route is giving a bad gateway in cloudflare, which means that your server isn't running (maybe it crashed?). These issues are best understood one at a time. It's not a CORS issue right now, cloudflare is giving a 502. Get your server running and make sure cloudflare resolves it correctly, then work on your CORS issue (if it exists). And don't use browser extensions to "work around it", they don't solve it and only confuse what the actual problem is.

I think I have it back to working with a combination of Cloudflare configs, but unfortunately, I am not confident in which settings are helping or not helping. All I know is that it works. So I dont really want to post an answer unless I can just say this...

What you've done you just enforced CORS middleware without configuring anything. Check this link for more deep technical knowledge.
However, below is CORS configuration blueprint that you can modify to accommodate your needs.
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// For CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const allowedOrigins = [
    'http://example1.com',
    'https://example2.com',
    'http://localhost:3016' // allow local development server
  ];

  const origin = req.headers.origin;

  // Check if the request origin is in the list of allowed origins
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin); // replace with '*' to allow all
  }

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"); // replace with '*' to allow all
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); // replace with '*' to allow all
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  next();
});

app.post("/api/v1/insert", async (req, res) => {

});


Everything here is accurate, but it doesn't solve (or even address) the OPs problem in any way. The default configuration for "enforcing CORS without configuring anything" is "allow every origin", so it still doesn't fix the OPs problem.

Tried this and it still didnt help :/ same errors

just doing app.use(cors()) is the most basic way of allowing cors, as it allows everything ....

@derpirscher thats what I show in my original post

@DanAshley My comment was meant for the BassamA, who suggested that manually setting the respective cors headers would solve the problem, which isn't the case
